# Counting objects in image with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an double array with xy coordinates for a bunch of pixels:
[x1, y1; x2, y2; ... xn, yn]

I want to count the number of groups of adjacent pixels I have, number each group, and know which pixels are part of each object.

What method(s) would you recommend?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a matlab example in the help.
However, you need the image processing toolbox

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/image-enhancement-and-analysis.html